# Set Bootstrap navbar transparency on scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I use a secondary fille called custom.css to overwrite the bootstrap code and I would like to know how to create a code that is activating only when the visitor of my site is not in the very top of the page.

Until now I created a transparent navbar using the default code provided by bootstrap. The only thing I have to do is to set it to execute: `background-color: #color` when the visitor is scrolling down.

Example: https://www.lyft.com/

When I  am in the top of the page, the navbar is transparent, but when I scroll down it becomes opaque.

Comment: Welcome to SO! `:)` What have you tried so far? Can you post your code? Lyft uses javascript to achieve that effect I believe.

Comment: I copied the original bootstrap for .navbar-default (if you need it, I can provide it to you) and I modified the colors. In HTML I set the bar to be top fixed (using navbar-fixed-top). I haven't done anything else except searching for something that might help... I will look into lyft, maybee I will find something usefull. EDIT: when I used "look into lyft" I meant looking into their css.

Comment: Lyft uses `angular-js` and adds the class `.opaque` to the navbar once the user scrolls to a certain point down the page.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it and try to learn how to use it :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ok you need the following code to achieve this effect: (I am going to use jQuery as it is the bootstrap supported language).

---

jQuery:

```
/**
 * Listen to scroll to change header opacity class
 */
function checkScroll(){
    var startY = $('.navbar').height() * 2; //The point where the navbar changes in px

    if($(window).scrollTop() > startY){
        $('.navbar').addClass("scrolled");
    }else{
        $('.navbar').removeClass("scrolled");
    }
}

if($('.navbar').length > 0){
    $(window).on("scroll load resize", function(){
        checkScroll();
    });
}
```

You can also use `ScrollSpy` to do this.

---

and your CSS (example):

```
/* Add the below transitions to allow a smooth color change similar to lyft */
.navbar {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
}

.navbar.scrolled {
    background: rgb(68, 68, 68); /* IE */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.78); /* NON-IE */
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to start it. I think because the bar is allready fixed on top. I will modify the script to watch another class. I think this will solve the problem.

Comment: using here with Bootstrap 4 in a Blazor project and it worked smoothly

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(this).scrollTop() > height) { 
           $('.navbar').addClass('scrolled');
       } else {
           $('.navbar').removeClass('scrolled');
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this fixes the problem? Your code might be correct, but you need to accompany it with good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the performance hit of using the scroll, load and resize events, you can now use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

It will allow you to detect if the content on your page has been scrolled, and set the nav bar transparency accordingly (by adding or removing a class).

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030607/4658957) for more details.