# navbar opacity/rgba change on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to create a nav that would be transparent at the top and would gain white color as the user scrolls down the page. My header height is `800px` and I want my nav to lose 100% of transparency after those `800px`. Here`s my code:

```
<header id="header">
   <nav class="navbar">
       <ul class="navigation">
           <li><a href="#header">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Our qualities</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
           <li><a href="">contact us</a></li>
       </ul>
   </nav>
```

```css
nav  {
    width: 1600px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; 

    ul {
        margin: 0 auto;

        li {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 5px 20px;

            a {
                font-family:  $f1;
                font-size: 16pt;
                color: $c3;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

First I tried with opacity, but it didn't work, and on top of that child elements (`ul` and `li`) had opacity of 0 as well.
Here`s the JS for that:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {        
    var navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        var navOpacity = scrollPos /800;
        jQuery('.navbar').css(opacity, 'navOpacity');

        if (jQuery('nav').css('opacity') < 1) {
            jQuery('.navigation').css('opacity', '1')  
        };
```

Then I tried to change RGBA value on scroll, that didn't work either
Instead of

```
jQuery('.navbar').css( opacity, 'navOpacity' );
```

I used

```
jQuery('.navbar').css(backgroundcolor, 'rgba (255, 255, 255, + "navOpacity")');
```

That failed as well, so, I have to ask you too help me

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646622/set-bootstrap-navbar-transparency-on-scroll

Comment: It actually isn`t. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646622/set-bootstrap-navbar-transparency-on-scroll
He asked about how to add or remove class scrolled, while im trying to edit navs opacity when scrolled, there is a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made `opacity` not a string, but the variable `navOpacity` has become a `string`. That was wrong. Everything else is working fine in general. :)

```
// change
$('.navbar').css(opacity, "navOpacity");

// to
$('.navbar').css("opacity", navOpacity);
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/arwanoww/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that you're providing `navOpacity` as a string to `css()`, instead of the variable itself. Try this:

```
$('.navbar').css('opacity', navOpacity);
```

Also note that your current logic is backwards to what you describe as your goal (the header starts transparent and becomes opaque at 800px) and the logic can also be simplified a lot. Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var pc = $(this).scrollTop() / 800;
    $('.navbar').css('opacity', 1 - pc);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/bta1hvbx/)

Comment: And `opacity`should be a string.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the advice but the error was, like you said, that I didn`t use opacity as a string and used my variable name as a stirng, and that went wrong, but after fixing that my code worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use jquery method `.fadeTo()` instead of `css('opacity')`. This method animates the opacity of the elements smoothly. It is easier to use and the animation is pretty good looking compared to instant opacity change.

```
jQuery('.navbar').fadeTo( "slow" , navOpacity);

if (jQuery('nav').css('opacity') < 1) {
  jQuery('.navigation').fadeTo( "slow" , 1);
};
```