# Bootstrap navbar change color to the scroll

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap for a theme, and I saw this site :http://www.luatix.org/en/ and I like the effect on navbar. Change color when scroll down and change color of elements.

Thanks

Comment: refer this link https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dylanholmes222/LaL3v/1/). Using Jquery to change the background color based on scroll pixel position.

Here is a [fiddle using bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/dylanholmes222/AzhN9/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#startchange');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
    if (startchange.length){
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $(".navbar-default").css('background-color', '#f0f0f0');
       } else {
          $('.navbar-default').css('background-color', 'transparent');
       }
   });
    }
});
```

Possible Duplicate of [Changing nav-bar color after scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706003/changing-nav-bar-color-after-scrolling)

Comment: It isn't the same effect of site !

Answer (score 0):

With pure Javascript:

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 5 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 5) {
    //change the background-color to white
  } else {
    //change the background-color to blue
  }
}
```