# CSS Change Navbar Background color when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My navbar has a white background, but it should be transparent on the landing page and white when i scroll down and white on every other page.

I used the code from: [Changing nav-bar color after scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706003/changing-nav-bar-color-after-scrolling)

EDIT:
So I added a fiddle with the answer below but somehow its not working

https://jsfiddle.net/jy6njukm/

Here's my code:

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var scroll_start = 0;
  var change_color = $('#change_color');
  var offset = change_color.offset();
  if (change_color.length){
    $(document).scroll(function() {
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
        // the white normal navbar
        $(".navbar-add").removeClass("navbar-trans");
      } else {
        // what the users sees when he lands on the page
        $(".navbar-add").addClass("navbar-trans");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Here is my navbar css:

```
.navbar-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 50;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.07),0 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
}
.navbar-trans {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

And I have my navbar html with only

```
<div class="navbar-fixed navbar-add">
.....
</div>
```

and my home.html.erb with

```
<div class="container-fluid banner bg-picture" id="change_color" 
  style="background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, 
  rgba(0,0,0,0.35) 50%), url('<%= asset_path('banner_logo.jpeg') %>')">
</div>
```

It kind of works but the problem now is, that everytime I refresh the page, the navbar is still white and it only turns transparent when I scroll up, to the top of the page. It turns white when I scroll down though, like I want it to be.

I inspected the page and everytime I refresh it, the background-color of the class is still white even though I set this to be transparent in the javascript?
How can I make it possible that the background-color of my navbar is transparent on my landing page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using HTML

Your HTML should be:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed navbar-add navbar-trans">
.....
</div>
```

Since it already contains the `navbar-trans` class, it will remain transparent. Once the user scrolls, the javascript will kick in, and remove/add `navbar-trans` class as per the code.

### Using JS

```
var landingPage = 'YOUR_LANDING_PAGE_URL';

function updateNavStyle() {
  if(landingPage.length > 0 && location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(landingPage.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
    var offset = $('#change_color').offset();
    var scroll_start = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_start > offset.top) {
      // the white normal navbar
      $(".navbar-add").removeClass("navbar-trans");
    } else {
      // what the users sees when he lands on the page
      $(".navbar-add").addClass("navbar-trans");
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var scroll_start = 0;
  var change_color = $('#change_color');

  if (change_color.length) {
    $(document).scroll(updateNavStyle);
    updateNavStyle(); // Note this.
  }
});
```

Here, in addition to binding the `updateNavStyle` function on scroll, I have added a call to it once the DOM is ready. As a result, as soon as the page loads, the function will be executed once and it will apply the styles based on scroll position.

Update:

If your landing page is 'index.html', where you want this function to work, write its value in variable `landingPage`. So the function will not run in other pages such as 'about.html' or 'contacts.html'.

Comment: Hi, but when I do this, my navbar is transparent on all my other sites

Comment: So do you have multiple pages using the same nav bar? I'm not sure how that works, but maybe you can try the JS solution I just added. If you are adding the javascript on specific sites, then this will fit your requirement.

Comment: yeah, I am using the same navbar on multiple pages and want them to be white. only transparent on the landing page though, i will try your solution now

Comment: Then, you could use `location.href` within the function `updateNavStyle` in order to check if the page is your landing page or not. If it is, then allow style changes, otherwise ignore the scroll event.

Comment: Do I have to change something in the js you gave me? I added navbar-trans to the html and changed my javascript file to the code you gave me. Now the navbar just stays transparent and won't turn white.

Comment: I had missed to add the variables earlier. Nevertheless, I just updated the code and answer. Hope it works.

Comment: I tried your solution, but unfortunately, the navbar-trans just makes my navbar transparent permantly. I added a fiddle to my post, check it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149828/discussion-between-wenqing-kevin-ma-and-nisarg-shah).