# How to properly handle Navbar color change on Scroll in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm making a project in angular. I would like to add a navbar which have transparent background initially but on scroll it will change its color. I am using bootstrap classes for that

My Navbar heading is html code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top">
    ...
</nav>
```

where can I add my Script to change its color on Scroll

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing nav-bar color after scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706003/changing-nav-bar-color-after-scrolling)

Comment: thats not working in my case because they have fixed navbar and im using sticky top. Moreover Im using angular where should i write script?

Comment: in terms of performance, it's much better to use the IntersectionObserver API
look at [https://blog.bitsrc.io/angular-maximizing-performance-with-the-intersection-observer-api-23d81312f178](https://blog.bitsrc.io/angular-maximizing-performance-with-the-intersection-observer-api-23d81312f178) for details

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve this with `@HostListner` in your `Typescript` file.

```
import { HostListener } from @angular/core;

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])

onWindowScroll() {
    let element = document.querySelector('.navbar') as HTMLElement;
    if (window.pageYOffset > element.clientHeight) {
      element.classList.add('navbar-inverse');
    } else {
      element.classList.remove('navbar-inverse');
    }
  }
```

Put scroll event on HTML part.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top" (scroll)="onWindowScroll();"></nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
   var $nav = $(".navbar-fixed-top");
   $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
 });
});
```

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css";

body {
  padding-top: 70px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.navbar-fixed-top.scrolled {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  transition: background-color 800ms linear;
}

.navbar-fixed-top.scrolled .nav-link {
  color:#555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <nav id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top">  
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#projects" class="nav-link">Teams</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#blog" class="nav-link">Service</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact-us" class="nav-link">Contact us</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
</header>



<h1>Folow</h1>

<p>
  "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
</p>
```

You Can See Here : [See CodeExample](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwg5kpqj/)

Answer (score 1):

Defining a scroll event is as easy as defining an `onscroll` attribute, like

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top" onscroll="myScroll()">
```

Let's implement `myScroll`. Scroll is a continous event and the tricky part is to catch its end. For this purpose we can do `setInterval`:

```
var scrollInterval = undefined;
var lastScroll = false;
function myScroll() {
    lastScroll = true;
    if (!scrollInterval) {
        //scroll has started, do some coloring
        lastScroll = false;
        scrollInterval = setTimeout(function() {
            if (!lastScroll) {
                //scroll has ended, revert the coloring
                scrollInterval = clearInterval(scrollInterval);
            }
            lastScroll = false;
        }, 100);
    } else {
        lastScroll = true;
    }
}
```