# Angular [ngClass] directive not working on scroll event

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-class

I'm using Angular 8 and bootstrap 4 to build a navbar which changes its color from transparent to dark when a certain amount to scroll happens. I'm using [ngClass] directive in order to achieve it. The function inside component.ts will return either true or false depending upon the scroll happened or not and ngClass will act accordingly. But I cannot unfortunately achieve it. Kindly take a look at my code below:

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-transparent" [ngClass]="{'navbar-inverse': scrollEvent($event)}">
```

**angular component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollEvent, true);
    }
scrollEvent = (event: any): void => {

      }
```

**css**

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #918d8d;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly handle Navbar color change on Scroll in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904628/how-to-properly-handle-navbar-color-change-on-scroll-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

1. *$event* is not defined in scope of HTML; some [explanation](https://angular.io/guide/user-input) how it works
2. Such as return type is `: void` - you are not returning `boolean`.

Approach to solving this would be setting the value(when needed) to something like `navbarInversed` and use it in the template

Don't use direct `addEventListener` - use [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) or RxJS's [fromEvent](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/fromevent)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765844/3474640) is a good example of what you need