# Angular [ngClass] should change navbar color on scrolling event

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm pretty much new in angular. I'm trying to achieve a functionality where the navbar will change from transparent to dark upon scrolling the page. But in my application the navbar remains transparent even after scrolling. How to achieve that?

The code which I tried:

HTML

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-transparent" [ngClass]="{'navbar-inverse': scrollEvent($event)}">
```

angular component.ts

```js
ngOnInit() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollEvent, true);
    }
scrollEvent = (event: any): void => {

      }
```

css

```css
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #918d8d;
}
```

Comment: This question is very similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59910252/1009922), posted two hours ago.

Comment: can I get a solution how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly handle Navbar color change on Scroll in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904628/how-to-properly-handle-navbar-color-change-on-scroll-in-angular)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the sample solution for your question [jsfiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scrolleventhandler-angular-using-hostlistener?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-transparent" [ngClass]="{'navbar-inverse': isScrolled}">
```

**angular component.ts**

Declare a variable(isScrolled) to handle add/remove a class to the nav element.

```
isScrolled = false;

@HostListener("window:scroll")
scrollEvent() {
    window.pageYOffset >= 80 ? (this.isScrolled = true) : (this.isScrolled = false);
}
```

Comment: Just to complete the answer... it can be simplified to: `this.isScrolled = window.pageYOffset >= 80;`.